# FB SDK produces a PHP Fatal error

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Starting now, a FB SDK integration that worked very well allowing people to login to our site via their Facebook account just stopped working. The server logs show the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in fb-sdk/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 191
```

We have not done any relevant code change that should have initiated it.
Have we missed an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Replace "$response['access_token']" with "$response->access_token" on line 186 and 187 in FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php

Comment: works for me man!